# Forwarding reference which binds to only one type?

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I want to have a forwarding reference which only binds to one type. I can use a static assert,
but I wonder if there is a more elegant (C++14/17) way to do this.

Here an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T> 
void f(T&& x) {
    // Is there a more elegant way to check for the type than the static_assert?
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::string, typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>::value);
    x = x + "Bar";   
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::string name("Foo");
  f(name);
  f(std::move(name));
}
```

Comment: You forgot to apply `std::remove_cv_t` to the result of `remove_reference`.

Comment: what about `requires (std::is_same_v<std::string, typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>)`

Comment: @asmmo: Thank you. But I am stuck with C++14/17. I updated the question to clarify.

Comment: You could move the check to a second template parameter and rely on SFINAE, but I would say this is the best, since you get a clear and direct error message. What would even be a more elegant solution then 1 single static_assert?

Answer (score 0):

You can use compile-time check using `std::enable_if`, as follows

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::string, typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>, void> f(T&& x) {
    x = x + "Bar";
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

If u can use c++20, this will be nicer, as follows

```
template<class T>
void f(T&& x)requires(std::is_same_v<std::string, typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>) {
    x = x + "Bar";
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++20 way:

```
template <typename T>
requires std::same_as<std::string, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
void f(T &&x) {}
```

C++17 way:

```
template <
    typename T,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_same_v<
            std::string,
            std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>
        >,
        std::nullptr_t
    > = nullptr
>
void f(T &&x) {}
```

The C++14 way is same as C++17, except you have to use `std::same_as<...>::value` instead of `std::is_same_v`.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve found myself in this problem too and didn’t have a solution until c++20, which is still not perfect.

```
template<typename T>
concept StringRef = std::is_same<std::string, typename std::remove_cv_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>::value;

void f(StringRef auto &&x)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: this a forwarding reference is not

Comment: I don't think `typename std::remove_cv_t` is valid, you need to drop the `typename`.